# How to only emit consistent calculations?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm using reactive programming to do a bunch of calculations. Here is a simple example that tracks two numbers and their sum:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    BehaviorSubject<int> x = new BehaviorSubject<int>(1);
    BehaviorSubject<int> y = new BehaviorSubject<int>(2);
    var sum = Observable.CombineLatest(x, y, (num1, num2) => num1 + num2);
    Observable
        .CombineLatest(x, y, sum, (xx, yy, sumsum) => new { X = xx, Y = yy, Sum = sumsum })
        .Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"X:{i.X} Y:{i.Y} Sum:{i.Sum}"));
    x.OnNext(3);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
X:1 Y:2 Sum:3
X:3 Y:2 Sum:3 
X:3 Y:2 Sum:5
```

Notice how second output result is "incorrect" because it is showing that 3+2=3. I understand why this is happening (x is updated before the sum is updated) but I want my output calculations to be atomic/consistent - no value should be emitted until all dependent calculations are complete. My first approach was this...

```
Observable.When(sum.And(Observable.CombineLatest(x, y)).Then((s, xy) => new { Sum = s, X = xy[0], Y = xy[1] } ));
```

This seems to work for my simple example. But my actual code has LOTS of calculated values and I couldn't figure out how to scale it. For example, if there was a sum and squaredSum, I don't know how to wait for each of these to emit something before taking action.

One method that should work (in-theory) is to timestamp all the values I care about, as shown below.

```
Observable
    .CombineLatest(x.Timestamp(), y.Timestamp(), sum.Timestamp(), (xx, yy, sumsum) => new { X = xx, Y = yy, Sum = sumsum })
    .Where(i=>i.Sum.Timestamp>i.X.Timestamp && i.Sum.Timestamp>i.Y.Timestamp)
    // do the calculation and subscribe
```

This method could work for very complicated models. All I have to do is ensure that no calculated value is emitted that is older than any core data value. I find this to be a bit of a kludge. It didn't actually work in my console app. When I replaced Timestamp with a custom extension that assigned a sequential int64 it did work.

What is a simple, clean way to handle this kind of thing in general?

=======

I'm making some progress here. This waits for a sum and sumSquared to emit a value before grabbing the data values that triggered the calculation.

```
var all = Observable.When(sum.And(sumSquared).And(Observable.CombineLatest(x, y)).Then((s, q, data) 
    => new { Sum = s, SumSquared = q, X = data[0], Y = data[1] }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Observable.CombineLatest(x, y, sum)
    .DistinctUntilChanged(list => list[2])
    .Subscribe(list => Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}={2}", list[0], list[1], list[2]));
```

It waits until the sum has been updated, which means that all its sources must have been updated too.

Comment: That is pretty simple. I'm still a bit troubled by these approaches. They require me to define dependencies between my observables when I create them and tailor my queries around these dependencies. In Excel, you just change one cell and everything gets updated; no intermediate invalid information to see. I wish there was a way to do that kind of thing here, like an Observable.CombineLatest(bool waitForSynchronousUpdatesToComplete).

Comment: Suppose IObservable<string> represents an email address and IObservable<bool> tells whether the email address is formatted correctly. If you want to display both pieces of information together, you shouldn't wait for a DistinctUntilChanged since the validation result might be unchanged. In this case, maybe it is better to do a Zip to correlate the input and matching output, and emit duplicate validation messages. Again - using the IObservable stuff requires too much knowledge about how the functions are defined. There should be a better way to make it work like Excel.

Comment: Your current setup is as parallel streams, there are lots of advantages to this, but it means that there is no ordering between the streams.

Comment: I just did some experimenting. If I don't do things like await Task.Delay I believe everything happens in synchronous order. So if I update x to 3 then 4 then 5, the results come back in that specific order. The the parallel complexity only happens if you go out of your way to make it happen. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You problem isn't because *`x` is updated before the sum is updated* per se. It's really about the way that you've constructed your query.

You've effectively created two queries: `Observable.CombineLatest(x, y, (num1, num2) => num1 + num2)` & `Observable.CombineLatest(x, y, sum, (xx, yy, sumsum) => new { X = xx, Y = yy, Sum = sumsum })`. Since in each you're subscribing to `x` then you've create two subscriptions. Meaning that when `x` updates then two lots of updates occur.

You need to avoid creating two subscriptions.

If you write your code like this:

```
BehaviorSubject<int> x = new BehaviorSubject<int>(1);
BehaviorSubject<int> y = new BehaviorSubject<int>(2);

Observable
    .CombineLatest(x, y, (num1, num2) => new
    {
        X = num1,
        Y = num2,
        Sum = num1 + num2
    })
    .Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"X:{i.X} Y:{i.Y} Sum:{i.Sum}"));

x.OnNext(3);
```

...then you correctly get this output:

```
X:1 Y:2 Sum:3
X:3 Y:2 Sum:5
```

Comment: I was attempting to build a bunch of little simple functions and then compose them together using operators like CombineLatest to build more complex functions. I get answers, but don't know what they are the answer to so outputing "x:1 y:2 sum:3" is hard. Your solution requires that each function emit the result and input parameters. This makes it easy to correlate inputs and outputs but it doesn't scale well for functions based on several layers of other functions.

Comment: @JustinM - Then you need to try `.Zip` and `.Publish` in your queries instead. The use of `.CombineLatest` is why your queries aren't working. Perhaps you could post a more complex example of what you're actually trying to and I could have a go at that?

Comment: @JustinM - `.Publish` limits the subscriptions to the source observables. If you have any hot observables you'll get unexpected values without `.Publish` in your kind of queries.

Answer (score 0):

I've started to get my head around this some more. Here is a more detailed example of what I'm trying to accomplish. This is some code that validates a first and last name, and should only generate a whole name when both parts are valid. As you can see I'm trying to use a bunch of small independently defined functions, like "firstIsValid", and then compose them together to calculate something more complex.

It seems like the challenge I'm facing here is trying to correlate inputs and outputs in my functions. For example, "firstIsValid" generates an output that says some first name was valid, but doesn't tell you which one. In option 2 below, I'm able to correlate them using Zip.

This strategy won't work if a validation function does not generate one output for each input. For example, if the user is typing web addresses and we're trying to validate them on the web, maybe we'd do a Throttle and/or Switch. There might be 10 web addresses for a single "webAddressIsValid". In that situation, I think I have to include the output with the input. Maybe have an IObservable> where the string is the web address and the bool is whether it is valid or not.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var first = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
    var last = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
    var firstIsValid = first.Select(i => string.IsNullOrEmpty(i) || i.Length < 3 ? false : true);
    var lastIsValid = last.Select(i => string.IsNullOrEmpty(i) || i.Length < 3 ? false : true);

    // OPTION 1 : Does not work
    // Output: bob smith, bob, bob roberts, roberts
    // firstIsValid and lastIsValid are not in sync with first and last
    //var whole = Observable
    //    .CombineLatest(first, firstIsValid, last, lastIsValid, (f, fv, l, lv) => new {
    //        First = f,
    //        Last = l,
    //        FirstIsValid = fv,
    //        LastIsValid = lv
    //    })
    //    .Where(i => i.FirstIsValid && i.LastIsValid)
    //    .Select(i => $"{i.First} {i.Last}");

    // OPTION 2 : Works as long as every change in a core data value generates one calculated value
    // Output: bob smith, bob robert
    var firstValidity = Observable.Zip(first, firstIsValid, (f, fv) => new { Name = f, IsValid = fv });
    var lastValidity = Observable.Zip(last, lastIsValid, (l, lv) => new { Name = l, IsValid = lv });
    var whole =
        Observable.CombineLatest(firstValidity, lastValidity, (f, l) => new { First = f, Last = l })
        .Where(i => i.First.IsValid && i.Last.IsValid)
        .Select(i => $"{i.First.Name} {i.Last.Name}");

    whole.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i));

    first.OnNext("bob");
    last.OnNext("smith");
    last.OnNext(null);
    last.OnNext("roberts");
    first.OnNext(null);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Another approach here. Each value gets a version number (like a timestamp). Any time a calculated value is older than the data (or other calculated values it relies upon) we can ignore it.

```
public class VersionedValue {
    static long _version;
    public VersionedValue() { Version = Interlocked.Increment(ref _version); }
    public long Version { get; }
}

public class VersionedValue<T> : VersionedValue {
    public VersionedValue(T value) { Value = value; }
    public T Value { get; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Value} {Version}";
}

public static class ExtensionMethods {
    public static IObservable<VersionedValue<T>> Versioned<T>(this IObservable<T> values) => values.Select(i => new VersionedValue<T>(i));
    public static VersionedValue<T> AsVersionedValue<T>(this T obj) => new VersionedValue<T>(obj);
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    // same as before
    //
    var whole = Observable
        .CombineLatest(first.Versioned(), firstIsValid.Versioned(), last.Versioned(), lastIsValid.Versioned(), (f, fv, l, lv) => new {
            First = f,
            Last = l,
            FirstIsValid = fv,
            LastIsValid = lv
        })
        .Where(i => i.FirstIsValid.Version > i.First.Version && i.LastIsValid.Version > i.Last.Version)
        .Where(i => i.FirstIsValid.Value && i.LastIsValid.Value)
        .Select(i => $"{i.First.Value} {i.Last.Value}");
```

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about what happens in deterministic order and what isn't. I've asked a similar but probably more clear question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364746/how-to-correlate-function-inputs-and-outputs